# Tips on initial assumptions for proofs using natural deduction - with a specific example.

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Here is a question that's been bugging me:

"Derive the following, using the rules of natural deduction:

$$
\vdash \neg(P_{1} \rightarrow P_{2}) \rightarrow P_{1} \vee P_{2}
$$

That is, give a derivation with no assumptions."

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if you guys have any general advice on how to play around with assumptions in these kinds of proofs? I often find myself struggling at the start, but once I'm convinced I have the correct assumptions, I can usually work through the question without too many issues. I'm particulary bad with negations, I tend to find...

Comment: It helps to work backwards: look at the expression you're trying to prove and think about which proof rules can produce an expression of that form. In this case your desired conclusion is of the form $A\to B$, so the last step will be an implication introduction (a.k.a. conditional proof) step using a sub-proof that assumes $A$ and derives $B$.

Comment: The trick is to note that the antecedent implies $P_1$. Thus, assume $\lnot P_1$ and derive $P_1 \to P_2$ and then a contradiction.